# Removing divs using Touchspin

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

In my front-end project I'm using Touchspin library by Virtuosoft. I've figured it out how to add new elements by pressing plus button, but when I'm trying to do opposite thing, remove one div when minus button is clicked, all divs are hiding instead of remove last one.

```
 $('.items-number').on('touchspin.on.startspin', function() {
     var mainRow = $(this).closest('.inner-items-row').siblings();

     if( !($(mainRow).hasClass('hidden')) ) {
         var newItem = $(mainRow).find('.single-item').first().clone();
         $(this).on('touchspin.on.startupspin', function() {
            $(newItem).appendTo(mainRow);
         });
         $(this).on('touchspin.on.startdownspin', function() {
            $(mainRow).find('.single-item').slice(-1).remove();
         });
       }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$('.items-number').on('touchspin.on.startspin', function() {
     var mainRow = $(this).closest('.inner-items-row').siblings();

     if( !($(mainRow).hasClass('hidden')) ) {
         var newItem = $(mainRow).find('.single-item').first().clone();
         $(this).on('touchspin.on.startupspin', function() {
            $(newItem).appendTo(mainRow);
         });
         $(this).on('touchspin.on.startdownspin', function() {
            //$(mainRow).find('.single-item').last().remove();
            $(newItem).remove();
         });
       }
    });
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work too. However, if I run my code for removing or yours in console, it works. It doesn't work from development code.

Comment: I have change for .last() may be it will work, is there a way to view inline?

Comment: Still same result. I think problem is that event is called before everything is set up.

Comment: I don't think so if as you said before all the divs are remove

Comment: They are hidden, after pressing plus button, all of them reveals, with new one.

Comment: If you reveal by pressing plus button so the newItem var should contain the new button so you could try $(newItem).remove(). I have change the answer.

Comment: Still not this. However behavior changed. Now it's hiding all except one, and when adding, multiplies divs.